# spring data find by for nested list object

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to write a findBy in the spring data where I want All employees where employees first department status is ACTIVE. Is it possible using spring data method name, without using custom query?

something like List findByDepartmentFirstStatusIsActive();

I tried few, but none are working so I guess No!!!

Comment: Try something like : findByDepartmentFirstStatus(FirstStatus status); or findByDepartment_FirstStatus(FirstStatus status);

Comment: I tried it but complains org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property firstStatus found for type Department

Comment: and _ is just to resolve conflict, so same error

Comment: That's because there is no property named firstStatus in Department. Can you show us your class Department ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use under score character `_` in order to separate nested property. For example:

```
findByDepartment_FirstStatus(Status status);
```

I assume that you have a property with name `firstStatus` of type `Status` in `Department` class, and obviously a field with name `department` of type `Department` in your `Employee` class (for example!).